# Wordpress - When clicking on posted in link, categories aren't filtering

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I have a new blog I am building here https://www.storageworks.biz/blog
When on a single post page such as https://www.storageworks.biz/blog/6-must-have-tips-for-moving-into-your-first-apartment/ when I go to the bottom and click on the posted in link to view other posts in the same category, it shows me all posts in place of only the one category type.

How do I set it up to filter out the results?

My code is as follows,

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id='page_wrapper'>
    <div id='page'>
        <div id='slider_wrapper' >

            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

            <div id='wrapper_right'>
                <div id="content">
                    <div id="nav-above" class="navigation">
                        <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_post_link( '%link', '<span class="meta-nav">«</span> %title' ) ?></div>
                        <div class="nav-next"><?php next_post_link( '%link', '%title <span class="meta-nav">»</span>' ) ?></div>
                    </div><!-- #nav-above -->
                    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                        <small><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> <!-- by <?php the_author() ?> --></small>
                        <div class="entry">
                            <?php the_content(); ?>
                        </div>
                        <p class="postmetadata"><?php the_tags('Tags: ', ', ', '<br />'); ?> Posted in <?php the_category(', ') ?> | <?php edit_post_link('Edit', '', ' | '); ?>  <?php //comments_popup_link('No Comments »', '1 Comment »', '% Comments »'); ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <?php //comments_template(); ?>
                    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
                    <div id="nav-below" class="navigation">
                    <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_post_link( '%link', '<span class="meta-nav">«</span> %title' ) ?></div>
                    <div class="nav-next"><?php next_post_link( '%link', '%title <span class="meta-nav">»</span>' ) ?></div>
                    </div><!-- #nav-below -->
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I'm running worpress version 4.5.3.

My template parts are made up of:
Header
index
single
sidebar
footer
functions

Thanks!